# Slow down AUTO_FOCUS parameter Android

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I have a camera application where Im using AUTO FOCUS Camera parameter to keep the focus. All I want is to take a time lapse of 3sec to adjust the focus instead of qucikly adjusting the focus. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
   if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
        // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
        // now you can start recording
         mMediaRecorder.start();

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
     //    mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
       // params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);


        final int a = params.getMaxZoom();
    //    params.setZoom(a);
         params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: use handler to delay it

Comment: but as i explained its a fixed parameter that I can give it to the user. How can I put a parameter in handler to take effect slowly?